# send Timestamp to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make all date in the fire base at the same time zone for users from all the world.
How I got the same result from this two lines of code , thought I changed the timezone of the date and still the local date give the same timestamp as UTC time zone?

```
        print(Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()).toDate());
        print(Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().toUtc()).toDate());
```

```
        print(Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()).toDate());
        print(Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().toUtc()).toDate());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime type has a [DateTime.utc() constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html) you can use to create a UTC time:

```
print(DateTime.now());
    print(DateTime.now().toUtc());
    print(DateTime.utc(
      DateTime.now().year,
      DateTime.now().month,
      DateTime.now().day,
      DateTime.now().hour,
      DateTime.now().minute,
      DateTime.now().second,
    ).toUtc());
```

By default, the DateTime.now() constructor is in the user's local time:

```
print(DateTime.now().isUtc); // false
```